# How delete item from listview with FutureBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter

i delete item from db from api. but, i need refresh listviews items or how delete 1 item from listview.
I using listview + FutureBuilder

Comment: `build()` and builders are to render the UI not to do actual work. Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Comment: How can i delete item from listview

Comment: Sorry, how can i make new render? setState don't give a result

Comment: Please, check my source code. seState() don't work
https://pastebin.com/PAZxbhRU

Comment: no, it are. This methods called before deletion

Answer (score 0):

Inside your setState method you need to add values.delete("here you add the thing you wanna delete"). Hope it helps :)

For example I do this with another List:

_deleteTodo (Todo todo, bool isDone)  => (isDone)?  todos.remove(todo): 
    debugPrint;